# Contraction of extension of prime ideals in an integral ring extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, integral-extensions

This is probably an easy question, but I don't know the answer:

> Let $R \subset S$ be an integral ring extension, and let $p$ be a prime ideal of $R$.
>   Then $p^{ec} = pS \cap R$ can be different from $p$.

We always have $p \subseteq pS \cap R$, so if $\dim(R)=0$ (or if $R$ is Dedekind; the case $p=(0)$ being trivial), then we have equality. So, what would be a counter-example?

Comment: Why do you think that $p^{ec}\ne p$? AFAIK, $p=P^c$ and $P^{cec}=P^c$.

Comment: @user26857 : Thank you for your comment. Maybe $p^{ec}=p$, but I wasn't able to show it. I know that there is a prime $q$ of $S$ such that $q^{c}=p$, but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [user26857](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/121097/user26857)'s helpful [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021116/contraction-of-extension-of-prime-ideals-in-an-integral-ring-extension#comment4148454_2021116) above, I think that I'm able to provide an answer.

By the lying-over property, there is a prime ideal $q$ of $S$ such that $q^c=p$. Then:
$$p^{ec} = q^{cec}=q^c=p.$$

This is wrong is $S$ is not integral over $R$, for instance $p=2\Bbb Z \triangleleft R=\Bbb Z \subset S=\Bbb Q$.

Comment: In fact, if $R\subset S$ is a ring extension and $p\subset R$ a prime ideal, then $p^{ec}=p\iff$ there is a prime $P\subset S$ such that $p=P^c$.